# Link to download doesn't work

Tags: php, html

When I click on a link, I can't download the image, only visualize it. What is my mistake?

PHP:

```
  require('conecta.php');
  ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);  
    $cSQL="SELECT ID_PIC, PIC, NOMBRE FROM FOTOS";
    $stmt=$oConni->prepare($cSQL) or die($oConni->error);
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $pic, $nombre);
    //$i=0;
    echo '<table cellspacing="0">';
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {

        if (!empty($pic)){ 
            echo'<tr><td><img class="sifoto" src="images.php? id='.$id.'" width="100" height="100"  /></td></tr>';
        }
        echo'<tr><td value='.$id.'><a href='.$nombre.'>DOWNLOAD</a></td></tr>'; 
        //$i++;
    }   
    $stmt->close();
    echo'</table>';

 ?>
```

Comment: What's in the `nombre` column of the table?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What link?  Where do you expect it to do?  What is supposed to link to?  What does it link to?  (P.S. Your `<a>` tag has nothing inside it)

Comment: when i click in Download, I want to download this image, but I only can watch it.

Comment: @jal: What is `$nombre`?  (Also, shouldn't `DOWNLOAD<a href='.$nombre.'></a>` be `<a href='.$nombre.'>DOWNLOAD</a>`?)

Comment: Quotes. That's the right answer.

Comment: $nombre is the name of the file to download

Comment: @WesleySchleumer: Good eye!  He needs to quote his `href` attribute.

Comment: @jal: What does the generated HTML look like (not the PHP code)?

Comment: @jal: it looks like KPheasey's answer would have helped you here. Would you consider accepting it? It is a good way to express thanks on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thgis question is similar to another.  Please check here - [Force file download with php using header()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485886/force-file-download-with-php-using-header)

You need to set the headers for a file transfer.

Comment: Make sure to set that header in the php file serving the image, not the one linking to it (which is what was pasted)

Answer (score 0):

As @WesleySchleumer said, you need to add quotes to the download link. change:

`echo'<tr><td value='.$id.'>DOWNLOAD<a href='.$nombre.'></a></td></tr>';`

to:

`echo'<tr><td value='.$id.'><a href="'.$nombre.'">DOWNLOAD</a></td></tr>';`

Comment: You should also probably put `DOWNLOAD` *inside* the `<a>` tag.

Comment: I just try it and the same... cant download the image.

Comment: @jal: What do you mean by "can't download"? What *exactly* happens when you click on the link?

Comment: When I click on the link the image is loaded in real size, but is not downloaded to save on disk

Comment: For that, you need to set a header for the image file. check this link @kpheasey provided http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485886/force-file-download-with-php-using-header