# Force reload images (in img) on back button press

Tags: caching, back, no-cache

There is a blog where I can post images and links, no scripts. I still want to have dynamic content.

My idea: image that has no-cache etc. headers and is dynamically generated by my own server-side php script. This image links to a page on my server, that sets cookie and does javascript history.back(). Then next time the image is downloaded, it is a different image.

Problem is, I can't get browsers to download the image again after back button is pressed...

I have set following headers:

```
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'); // HTTP 1.1.
header('Pragma: no-cache'); // HTTP 1.0.
header('Expires: 0'); // Proxies.
```

Still for some reason if the image is inside a  tag, the old version is loaded from cache when going back.

Also I included the image on the seccond page, so browser did even download the new version of the image, but when i pressed the back button, I was still presented with the old version...

How can I force browser to download the image again?

Comment: You are working on desktop browsers, right? the back button is not the Android's one, right?

Comment: yeah, desktop browsers are in question, ff, chrome, and maybe also ie, very broad supprot not required :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to append a number at the end of your image source:

```
<img src="image.jpg?1" />
```

If your last image with the same name is `image.jpg` your number after ? will force the browser to download the image

So If your last image with the same name is:

```
<img src="image.jpg?1" />
```

You have to change it to

```
<img src="image.jpg?2" />
```

You can have a random generator number and put it at the end src, so every time your browser start to download your image

Comment: I can not control the img tag dynamically, no scripting on the blog... I have to write the img tag beforehand, and then I hope to be able to change, what the tag points to

Comment: did you see this link?
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485886/force-file-download-with-php-using-header)

Comment: hmm, this seems to be about a different kind of problem, dont'd see how it could help me

Comment: did you tried to use PHP output content type? `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');` use PHP function to output your image. functions like `imagejpeg`. you can use `SimpleImage` which is available in `https://gist.github.com/miguelxt/908143`

Comment: In fact I tested with a svg image that was preprocessed and outputted by php (svg is xml basically), so I indeed outputed the image from php and used content-type to set it to image, "image/svg+xml"