# How can I Upload a document file in Wordpress and track its download?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, download

I am creating my document-sharing site using wordpress. But I have problems when doing a Upload-file form and Download tracking.
Of course I make it front-end. I want to ask you for help about how can I track the uploaded file --> To make "Popular Download Document" and make "Download History" in user's profile.
Or could you help me something like that. Many thanks !

Comment: Do you want to keep track of Uploaded documents or Downloaded docs ?

Comment: save data in database i mean when some one click download it will save history in database so you can get query the highest number of download

Comment: I want to keep track of Downloaded documents @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$mysql_query = "UPDATE `download` SET `counter_download` = counter_download + 1";

// Execute your Query with your mysql or mysqli or pdo ...
// Then, let user download file with php function force_download().

force_download("/folder/file.zip");
```

Finally call your column where you insert download counter.

Comment: Could you help me solve this, as I had asked, how can I get user downloaded file? For example, when an user logged-in and download a file, then they go to "Download History" and that file was there. Thank you

Comment: do you want these data will be stored in a new mysql table for tracking downloads?

Answer (score 0):

To get track of downloaded document, use one field in your database table named as `num_downloads`. See when you hit some download page like `abc.com/downloads.php?id=10`, now downloads.php will be your page and you have query string id=10. So for that product increment/update its num_downloads by one as soon as it gets hit. So 20 times Only i clicked on link, then count for that file will be +20 than original num_downloads count.

So roughly your table structure for say table `files` will be

```
id   name_of_file        num_downloads
1    harry potter book   100
```

Where num_downloads field will increment by one on each hit for particular file.

Comment: Okay. I understood. Let me try this. Thank you so much !

Comment: By the way, I have one more question. How can I get user downloaded file? For example, when an user logged-in and download a file, then they go to "Download History" and that file was there @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com

Comment: @Tienluc you are just 1 step away from googling . Here is ready made answer just for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485886/force-file-download-with-php-using-header