# zip and download from nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, download

I am trying to zip the file and download from server using easy-zip module. But now I can write into a server using following code but how can i make it downloadable???

```
var app = require('express')();
var easyzip = require('easy-zip');

app.get('/api/downloadFile',function(req,res){
    console.log("inside req");
    var data = "<html><body><h1>Inside new Html</h1></body></html>";
    var zip2 = new easyzip.EasyZip();
    var jsFolder = zip2.folder('data');
    jsFolder.file('app.js','alert("hello world")');
    jsFolder.file('index.html',data);
    zip2.writeToFile('folder.zip');
});
```

Comment: Send the appropriate headers. Example (although for PHP) can be seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8485963/1169798

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `zip2.writeToResponse(res,'folder.zip');` instead of `zip2.writeToFile('folder.zip');`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of write into a file write into a response

```
var app = require('express')();
var easyzip = require('easy-zip');

app.get('/api/downloadFile',function(req,res){
    console.log("inside req");
    var data = "<html><body><h1>Inside new Html</h1></body></html>";
    var zip2 = new easyzip.EasyZip();
    var jsFolder = zip2.folder('data');
    jsFolder.file('app.js','alert("hello world")');
    jsFolder.file('index.html',data);
    zip2.writeToResponse(res,'folder');
    res.end();
})
```