# Php or Apache? Content of zip file is diplayed instead of downloading zip file

Tags: php, apache, download

I tried to write a php-script to create and download a zip file. When I tested the script on my localhost, the download works, but when it's uploaded to the server, things go wrong: instead of downloading the zip file, the content of the file is displayed in the browser.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

The code

```
   $zip = new ZipArchive();
   $zip->open("$maand/zipfile.zip", ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
   $zip->addFile("$maand/ant/a_nb.txt", 'ant.txt');
   $zip->addFile("$maand/lim/l_nb.txt", 'lim.txt');
   $zip->addFile("$maand/oos/o_nb.txt", 'oos.txt');
   $zip->addFile("$maand/vla/v_nb.txt", 'vla.txt');
   $zip->addFile("$maand/wes/w_nb.txt", 'wes.txt');
   $zip->close();
   $filename = "zipfile.zip";
   $filepath = "$maand/";
// headers for zip downloads
   header("Pragma: public");
   header("Expires: 0");
   header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
   header("Cache-Control: public");
   header("Content-type: application/zip");
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"");
   header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filepath.$filename));
   ob_end_flush();
   @readfile($filepath.$filename);
```

Comment: Take a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485886/force-file-download-with-php-using-header You have to set up the right header.

Comment: you don't need `ob_end_flush();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you missing `ob_start()`

example:

```
    header('Content-Type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="' . $download . '"');
    ob_start();
    $str = '';
    if(file_exists($file) === true){
        $str = file_get_contents($file);
    }
    ob_end_clean();
    echo $str;
```