# Force download dialog for an image with PHP

Tags: php

I have in my `index.php` a link like this:

```
<a href="download.php?url=http://example.com/image.jpg">Download</a>
```

I need that when you click that link the download dialong opens to save the foto with a specific name like `myfile123.jpg`.

In my `download.php` I have this:

```
header('Content-type:image/jpeg');

$handle = fopen($_GET['url'], "rb");
while (!feof($handle)) {
  echo fread($handle, 8192);
}
fclose($handle);
```

And while it retrieves the image, it just opens it in the same tab (instead of forcing the dialog).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force file download with php using header()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485886/force-file-download-with-php-using-header)

Comment: look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485886/force-file-download-with-php-using-header

Comment: `<a download href="download.php?url=http://example.com/image.jpg">Download</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add another `header`, in order to trigger the download, like:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="image.jpg"');
```

> More info about the `Content-Disposition` header, here: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Comment: Glad to help @nick

Answer (score 3):

Take a look on the [PHP readfile example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

Example from php.net:

```
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
```

Comment: Deleted my previous comment saying it worked, it has a problem. While it forces the download dialog, when I download the image it is empty...

Comment: Check also the path and if the file exists