# Displaying files from the share folder by using php (Google Chrome)

Tags: php, xml, file-get-contents, smb, file-sharing

I need to open xml file in php page. The file is located in share folder that I made on my PC. File is accessible from other PC's that are connected to the server. How can I do that?
Thank you!

Have tried this:

```
$file_read = file_get_contents('file:///10.8.8.89/test/20180716_BT-0444-0445.xml');
$file_read = preg_replace('/&amp;/', ' and ', $file_read);
echo $file_read;
```

but code acts like the file doesn't exist. 
Before that I took xml files from the ftp server and it worked fine.

Comment: try removing `file:///`, or the IP if it isn't being served up by apache or nginx

Comment: @delboy1978uk doesn't work :(

Comment: it should either be `file:///actual/path/to/file`, or `http://10.8.8.89/etc/etc`. Try both in the browser first

Comment: @delboy1978uk `file://10.8.8.89/test` works fine and opens the directory, but `http://10.8.8.89/test` doesn't open at all

Comment: that's bizarre. You don't have a folder with that ip as the name do you? :-P

Comment: @delboy1978uk I shared the folder so now I can type `\\10.8.8.89\test` in file explorer or browser and open it. It's now shared with all server users. And it has all the permissions for others to open it.

Comment: but it isn't going through a windowqs server? it's a network share? what is the full absolute path on your hard drive?

Comment: @delboy1978uk C:\test. It's a network share

Comment: ok, try `file://C:/test/20180716_BT-0444-0445.xml`

Comment: @delboy1978uk now it opens xml from ftp server. It should give error or smthng like this, but it opens xml, which needs to be open in previous site version...

Comment: i don't know what you mean

Comment: @delboy1978uk The idea of the site is to get the xml file from server and display it. On the page you have lots of buttons with numbers, so different button opens different xml. Now I need to get access to the archive folder and display xml files from there not using ftp, but somehow through the SMB. When I entered `file://C:/test/20180716_BT-0444-0445.xml` it was still opening files as if I was using ftp.

Comment: look up how to set headers in php to make it download instead of open ;-)

Comment: @delboy1978uk ok, thank you!

Comment: if it works let me know and i'll write a proper answer so other people can see it

Comment: @delboy1978uk I'll let u know if I'll find something :)

Comment: look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485886/force-file-download-with-php-using-header

Comment: @delboy1978uk actually, I cant do that. It's not possible, because user doesnt need to download the file, site must open files in new tab and display them.

Comment: @delboy1978uk concept is: You click the button, file downloads to the folder on the website hosting and than website displays the file to user. As user quits, file deletes from the folder to empty the space.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the content type in the headers
then the browser can correctly display xml

```
$file_read = file_get_contents('file:///10.8.8.89/test/20180716_BT-0444-0445.xml');

header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo $file_read;
```

Comment: I'd say that I have a problem with actually getting the file from share folder, but not with displaying it in browser.