# How to prevent users from downloading source code files using the PHP download option I have for downloading pdf files in my web application?

Tags: php, security, extjs

**Download.php**

```
<?php 
$file = $_GET['file'];
if(file_exists($file)) {
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
}
?>
```

Following is the JavaScript code I'm using to pass the url to php script:
**Download.js**

```
init:function(){
    this.control({
        '#downloadSite': {
            load:function(tree, node, records, successful, eOpts)
            {

            },

            itemclick:  function(tree, record, item, index)
            {
                if(record.get('id') == 300){
                    window.open('Download.php?file=../TAB/'+record.get('url'));
                }
                else{
                    window.open('Download.php?file=../PDF/'+record.get('url'));
                }                   
            },
            beforeitemclick:  function(tree, record, item, index)
            {
                if(record.get('leaf') == false) return false;
            },
            beforeitemdblclick: function(){
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

If I am entering "Download.php?file=../web.config" in the url , web.config file is being downloaded. I want to prevent direct download of source code. the download option is for downloading pdf files that I have stored in the pdf's folder in the main directory.

Please help !!

Comment: alexJoe, if you run the PHP file manually, create the URL manually and run it, no JavaScript, does it do the same?

Comment: does this help?  I don't want to vote this has already been solved (a.k.a closed), if it doesn't help you.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485886/force-file-download-with-php-using-header

Comment: The other script is the problem?  Sorry.  Didn't understand.

Comment: No, is there a way I can prevent downloading of source code files if someone just alters the url like this "Download.php?file=../web.config".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've fallen fowl of a pretty bad design decision here that makes you [vulnerable to file system traversal](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/File_System#Path_traversal).

You might consider:

1. Ensure the requested file ends in .pdf
2. Ensure that the file being read ends in .pdf
3. Drop any requests where the file parameter contains  `..`

Given Download.php doens't look to be ensuring requesters are authenticated at all, I would suggest maybe having your PDF documents live within a web accessible directory and just linking directly to them, instead of creating an attack vector that could compromise your server.

Comment: Thanks Michael,it wokred ! I have added validations if the file being requested is pdf,csv.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in web.config,

```
<authorization>
    <allow users="user1, user2"/>
    <deny users=”?”/>
</authorization>
```

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/815151/how-to-restrict-specific-users-from-gaining-access-to-specified-web-re

Don't allow the code to circumvent this, as Michael M is saying.