# Generate and download XML file with Laravel

Tags: php, xml, laravel

I'm trying to generate a XML file using Laravel. Starting from the Controller, where I generate the data that I need to use on the XML file. I generate the XML file using a blade template but I can't save the file or download it automatically

```
$xml_datos = [];
$total = 0;

.
.
.

$output = View::make('site.contabilidad.adeudosXML')->with(compact('xml_datos', 'total'))->render();

$xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?> \n <Document xmlns=\"urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02\">" .$output;

return $xml;
```

I need the file to be downloaded, not showed. I've tried using the class Storage and Filesystem but none of them seems to work

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#retrieving-files has a section "Downloading Files", see if that helps. Or use headers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485886/force-file-download-with-php-using-header

Answer (score 5):

You could create a [Response](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses) like this:

```
 public function saveXML()
    {
        $output = View::make('site.contabilidad.adeudosXML')->with(compact('xml_datos', 'total'))->render();

        $xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?> \n <Document xmlns=\"urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02\">" .$output;

        $response = Response::create($xml, 200);
        $response->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        $response->header('Cache-Control', 'public');
        $response->header('Content-Description', 'File Transfer');
        $response->header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' . yourFileNameHere . '');
        $response->header('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary');
        return $response;
    }
```

Also, i strongly recommend you using the [PHP functions to manipulate XML](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/simplexml.examples-basic.php).