# php file_put_contents save in local client real path

Tags: php, save, filepath, realpath

I am using `file_put_contents` and the path is `C:\foldername` its working fine in my local. When I tried it on my dev ennvironment I thought its not working because its not saving in my computer. It is saving in my dev environment.

`file_put_contents("C:\foldername", $data);`

1. How to use this and have the path to point to client computer?
2. What should i put in the path so that it will be stored in the client of users not on dev environment?

Comment: PHP runs on the server, not the client. It can't put to a file on the client, you need to download the file for that.

Comment: @Barmar is there a way I can save a file to client's computer? other than the `file_put_content` if its not possible for `file_put_content`  to do what i need?

Comment: You need to use to headers. Take a read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485886/force-file-download-with-php-using-header