# How to make a button, that when you click it downloads an excel file (phpspreadsheet)

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this code below.  I am taking an existing excel called b1b5.xls and i am putting some values as you can see.. The problem is that i don't know how to assosiate a button that when i click it, the b1b5.xls is been downloaded with my values..

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<center>
  <button onclick=" somefunction ?? ">Download!</button>
</center>


</body>
</html>

<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;



$spreadsheet = IOFactory::load('b1b5.xls');
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

$sheet->setCellValue('C7', 'Myvalue');
$sheet->setCellValue('C8', 'Myvalue2');


foreach (range('A', 'E') as $col) {
    $sheet->getColumnDimension($col)->setAutoSize(true);
}

$filename = 'trapezas_ellados.xlsx';
// Redirect output to a client's web browser (Xlsx)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $filename . '"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT'); // always modified
header('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.

$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save('php://output');
?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to trigger a file download when clicking an HTML button or JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620698/how-to-trigger-a-file-download-when-clicking-an-html-button-or-javascript)

Comment: I have seen this .. no

Comment: Please do elaborate on that. How exactly does the linked question not solve your problem? Do you not want the button to cause the file to be downloaded? Because that is precisely what the code in the linked post does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the php code in another page and make the download in side form with method post .
in the page_with_code_to_generate_the_excel.php

```
if(isset($_POST){ ..PUT THE PHP CODE HERE}
```

that's how I did it it work every time, I hope my answer helped you ^_^

Comment: i think that this is the right way... but i have one question about that. Can i do this if i have 2 spreadsheets ? One that i am loading an existing file.. and another one that i am creating from the beginning by myself?

Comment: u can make it for multi  spreadsheets  in this method just add another php page with different content for you excel , if you want to download excel file don by Microsoft office  you can just upload your work and make user download it from your site , if you see my answer helped you please marck my comment as correct answer

Comment: so if i do this.. it is kinda the same way like the answer above ?  `<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>` but your answer it is more well structured?

Comment: For your already excel file done by Microsoft office its the easy way to do that  <a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>  , for your dynamic content you must done it inside the php page , ^_^

Comment: Ok i understand, so if i want to do it with your away.. my form will have `action="downloadExcel.php"` for example and code will be with the isset tag etc... i am going to test it

Comment: this is not (MY WAY) but it is one of the easiest way to do it  , an you can do it without action ="downlaod.php" you can just include the downlaod.php page ^_^

Answer (score 3):

You can use the download attribute in anchor tag. It can contain extensions like .img, .pdf, .txt, .html, etc.
Here is an example

```
<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>
```

Comment: @Hanzalo Saeed this would work but he wants to dynamically fill that file on download. At least if I am not mistaking the original question.

Comment: Can i have all the code in one and only index.php? I am asking that because if i do this `<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>` inside the `href` i will have to place the name of my one and only index.. So if i load  index, it is downloading right away and not if someone click it. So i guess i must have 2 scripts ? one html index and one php ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you wanna separate your HTML and PHP Script.

In your HTML link to your PHP Script processing the excel file and send the correct headers for forcing the file to download, see this Stackoverflow question:

[Force file download with php using header() - by User: Kerp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485886/force-file-download-with-php-using-header)