# fpdf works properly if i call the controller and doesnt work if i call it through jquery

Tags: php, pdf-generation, fpdf

I am able to get the output of a pdf using fpdf, the problem is that i am not to generate it if the call the function through jquery... rather the pdf is display in firebug?How to solve this issue

output display in firebug

```
%PDF-1.3
3 0 obj
<</Type /Page
/Parent 1 0 R
/Resources 2 0 R
/Contents 4 0 R>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Filter /FlateDecode /Length 582>>
stream
x���Ms�0���{LU���͞&�v�L�p��b��N��`Zc���k,ĳ��Bgh��b���{�|�����șP`�f�B���sS��C���*+�[H��K�ŁO��מ�����M:<�3�jt�:Z��1,�`�ˤc
�Ҁ��        ��0���~��^��U�  �;�q�_6y
y�� ��+Q�6��e/���C%�ً+�!q5+�Sf
```

jquery:

```
        $.post(url+"/create_pdf",js,function(data){

        },"json");
```

Comment: You can't use ajax to let the browser show the "download" file dialog. But there's [a workaround using a hidden <iframe>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599670/ajax-file-download-using-jquery-php). Maybe that solves your Problem.

Comment: can u tell me the proper changes  what i have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instread of $.post() (which will run the PDF gnerator and return contents to AJAX), you should redirect the user to the url in the browser: i.e. use

```
window.location.href=url+"registration/create_member?" + $.param(js);
```

You will need to convert your PDF generating function to accept $_GET, not $_POST

Alternatively, generate the pdf file as you are doing but store on server (temporarily) and pass the url back through ajax, Then ajax redirects the user to that temporary file location through windows.location.href instead.

Comment: But it is not taking the value of json? rather it displays blank except the labels

Comment: Have you set the php to accept get variables as opposed to post? $this->input->get