# How can I use $.post function in javascript to visit a page with post method to download a file?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post

I want to  write a file-download page for customers to download files from my company servers.

And I don't want to expose the real file link to users, so I have two pages : filelist.php for offering a link to click and posting the file name as parameter to the other page, named download.php , accepting the request and transferring file stream to customers.

The key part of download.php is like this:

```
$fp = fopen($real_file_path,'r');
$file_size = $temp_res['ef_file_bytes'];
Header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
Header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
Header("Accept-Length: ".$file_size);
Header("Content-Disposition: attachement;filename=".$file_name);
echo fread($fp,$file_size);
fclose($fp);
exit;
```

Now I use an onclick() function in filelist.php ,when the file link is clicked ,the function following is called:

```
function downloadfile( ef_name )
    {
        var url_str='download.php';
        url_str = encodeURI(url_str);
        $.post(
        url_str,{fnm:ef_name },
        function(data){
            window.open().document.write(data);
          }
          ); 
    }
```

But I can only show the file's content in page rather than popping up a dialog-window to save it.

If I use  to test , it works well.

The the 'data' in JS code above is exactly the whole content of the file I want to down load. I think the question is in the function I used in $.post(); Is there any function in javascript can open a new page with post parameter ?

I'm on windows , apache ,php,mysql.Thanks!

Comment: [How to download a file by jquery.ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/how-to-download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax)

Comment: [Ajax File Download using Jquery, PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599670/ajax-file-download-using-jquery-php)

Comment: You should consider looking for existing Q/A with the same topic.

Comment: @PradeepSanjaya, the OP wants it to be through POST method because that's how he receives data on the other side.
Your links only show how to do it through GET.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `$.post` but you can create a hidden `form` with `method="POST"` and submit it.
Optionally a hidden `iframe` to use as `target` to recieve the result.

Comment: yeah , thanks, it does work when I use a form with 'POST' method.It will be much easier . So I counldn't find a way using JS code to send a post request and pop up a dialog window to save files ? I just feel strange -_-|

Comment: you can use JS to form.submit()... unfortunately. To send a post and recieve binary data you would have to open a `socket` and assemble the request yourself, the $.ajax() method won't help you and neighter will the XMLHttpRequest object...